# Is it possible to enforce password complexity server-side while using salted hashed passphrases?

Tags: hash, salt

If I'm using server-side passphrase complexity rules and I'm salting and hashing the passphrase on the client-side is it possible to test complexity rules once the password reaches the server? I would assume not or hashing is not very useful

So in this case how do you enforce password complexity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer; you shouldn't be hashing passwords client-side. If you do so, the submitted hash effectively becomes a plain-text password.

There are many posts on SO and related sites that explain why this is a bad idea in more depth. For example, https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/23006/client-side-password-hashing

EDIT: To answer your original question, if a password has been hashed and salted correctly then there should be no way to recover the original password from the hash.

Comment: I'm confused, if you don't hash it client-side then you ARE submitting a plain text password which can be captured by man in the middle attacks. Assume that we hash client side and  again once it reaches server side to work around this, we still have the issue of being unable to enforce server-side password complexity rules

Comment: To avoid submitting plain-text passwords susceptible to man in the middle attacks, an encrypted communications protocol is normally used. The most common example would be HTTPS. I recommend reading this on how to handle passwords, http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/33793/handling-passwords-in-a-web-application.